# removing the HTML inside the renderer in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to remove the button which is placed inside the renderer of the grid column.
But What I did removed all the buttons from that column:

```
_rendererImportBtnDisplay : function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex,   colIndex, store, view) {
        var loop = store.getRange();
        Ext.each(loop,function (record) {
              var btn = record.data.importButton;
          if(btn == true){
                return "";
              }
          }else{
              return "<span class='btn_import_file'><button>Import</button></span>";
          }
     });
},
```

But I want to remove only the buttons where:

```
var btn = record.data.importButton;
```

returns

```
true
```

for the specific columns.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.each` applies a function to each member of an array. It’s basically a more convenient form of a for loop. Return false from each function will stop the iteration. But it will not cause a return from the container function as you are trying to do. You should have written the code as shown below, since record is available as a parameter from `renderer` function.

```
_rendererImportBtnDisplay : function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex,   colIndex, store, view) {          
       if(record.data.importButton == true){
           return "";
       }else{
           return "<span class='btn_import_file'><button>Import</button></span>";
       }
}
```

Comment: can skip record.data.importButton == true and just check record.data.importButton :)

Comment: I guess I tried to do a bit too much..Didn't realize how render-er worked :D